# Android Custom Gridview Adapter Bug Arrangement Changes if scrolled

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, custom-adapter

I have an app that has a custom gridview adapter that inflates image and string, the image is inflated using string array that contains file path of the image from ExternalFilesStorage.

The problem is that everytime I scroll down and up of the gridview the contents rearrange themselves randomly but when i click it the text result of the onclick is different from the clicked item, the text result is the same with the correct arrangement.

Here are the codes for the custom adapter:

```
 public class PTSCustomGridView extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] pictureNameArray;
    private final String[] picturePathArray;

    public PTSCustomGridView(Context context, String[] pictureNameArray, String[] picturePathArray) {
        mContext = context;
        this.pictureNameArray = pictureNameArray;
        this.picturePathArray = picturePathArray;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pictureNameArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View gridViewAndroid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridViewAndroid = new View(mContext);
            gridViewAndroid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gridview, null);
            TextView textViewAndroid = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_text);
            ImageView imageViewAndroid = (ImageView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_image);
            textViewAndroid.setText(pictureNameArray[i]);
            //set Image from file path
            File imgFile = new File(picturePathArray[i]);
            if(imgFile.exists()){
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                //ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
                imageViewAndroid.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        } else {
            gridViewAndroid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridViewAndroid;
    }
}
```

Here are the codes for the onClickListener:

```
PTSCustomGridView adapterViewAndroid = new PTSCustomGridView(PictureToSpeechActivity.this, pictureNameArray, picturePathArray);
        androidGridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.PTSGridView);
        androidGridView.setAdapter(adapterViewAndroid);
        androidGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int i, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(PictureToSpeechActivity.this, "GridView Item: " + gridViewString[+i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                    Toast.makeText(PictureToSpeechActivity.this, "Feature not supported on your device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    pitch = sharedPref.getFloat("pitch", 1);
                    speed = sharedPref.getFloat("speed", 1);
                    language = sharedPref.getString("language", "UK");
                    text = pictureNameArray[i];
                    ettext.setText(text);
                    TTS.setPitch(pitch);
                    TTS.setSpeechRate(speed);
                    ttsLanguage();
                    TTS.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is it seriously working? I don't think so...

Comment: its working. all the functions and databases are working. my only problem is the rearrangement when scrolled

Comment: can you share that parts of the code where you are listening to the click event...

Comment: Edited: added the code for onItemClick. PS. There are no errors when running